# Looking for Cells with length of 2 characters or 1 character

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for  cells with length of value 1 or 2 characters.
This is code:

```
Set c = .Find(Len(c.Value) = 2 Or 1, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: You could use wildcards "??" and "?".   But I don't think you can search for both at the same time and will need to do them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop rather than *FIND()*:

```
Sub durale()
   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If Len(r.Value) = 2 Or Len(r.Value) = 1 Then
         Set c = r
         Exit For
      End If
   Next r

   If c Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "nothing found"
   Else
      MsgBox "cell " & r.Address(0, 0) & "contains " & r.Value
   End If
End Sub
```